# How can I make Emacs query the user before saving a file (and abort if the user answers no)?

Tags: emacs, elisp, save, savefiledialog

I want to add an extra prompt asking the user if they are sure they want to save the file, but only for files in certain "protected" directories. Assume I have a function `file-needs-protection-p` that takes a file name and returns t if the user should be queried before saving that file. How can I get Emacs to ask something like `"This file is protected. Are you sure you want to modify it?"` when the user tries to save such a file, and then make Emacs abort the save if the user answers no?

Hopefully there is some special hook somewhere where I can add a function that uses `yes-or-no-p`, and Emacs will abort the save if the function returns false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but I think you should be able to use `before-save-hook` to perform your test and ask your question, and simply raise an error if they answer no:

```el
(error "Save aborted by user")
```

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. I didn't know you could use error in a hook to break out of the associated function, very neat.

Comment: I guess this is a fine solution. I wish there was a less blunt way of doing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got `file-needs-protection-p` already, I think the rest is straightforward:

```
(defun save-buffer-check 
  "If the current buffer is a protected file, query the user before saving."
  (if (file-needs-protection-p (buffer-file-name))
      (if (y-or-n-p 
           "This file is protected. Are you sure you want to modify it?")
          (save-buffer))
    (save-buffer)))
```

Rebind that to `C-x C-s` and see if it does what you need. I don't think you need any special hooks or advice, just a function that inserts a call to your predicate before either calling `save-buffer` or just returning without doing anything.

Comment: For personal use, this is probably fine, but I am thinking of doing this in an Emacs package (to protect the user from modifying files that are supposed to be managed automatically), so I can't really ask the user to rebind such fundamental keybindings. A hook would be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: so put the binding in your mode keymap, then it only applies to buffers that use your mode. Or use phils' answer and add logic to check for the current major mode before calling your check. I think you can get what you want from one or both of these answers.